# what is replacement of getLocation() function of google maps api v2 javascript in v3 javascript?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have google maps application of v2 javascript where I used getLocation() function. Now I want to convert my application from v2 to v3. But I haven't see any function of same task is available in v3. Can anyone say is there any function available and if yes then please name the function or if not then if anybody could then let me know how to do the task in v3.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In v3, we use geocoder.geocode() instead of GClientGeocoder.getLocation().

Check this page.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding